# Python: some pygame objects do not appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm building a game where you have to dodge bricks on a road.  The blocks will appear but the little white lines in the center of the window (the lane separators are blocks so they can move) won't and it crashes the game when I load it up!

This is the code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
             #Colour Acronym Chart
#|  Black = Blck  |  Grey = Gry   | Dark = Drk    | White = Wht
#|  Deep = Dp     |  Metal = Mtl  | Light = Lht   | Cyan = Cyn
#|  Blue = Bl     |  Baby = Bby   | Maroon = Mrn  |
#|  Red = Rd      |  Fire = Fr    | Orange = Orng |

# Window Colour Index
Wht = (255, 255, 255)
Blck = (0, 0, 0)            
Dp_Gry = (32, 32, 32)       
Mtl_Gry = (96, 96, 96)    
Lht_Gry = (160, 160, 160)

Dp_Bl = (0, 0, 102)
Lht_Bby_Bl = (0, 128, 255)
Cyn = (0, 153, 153)

Drk_Mrn = (102, 0, 0)
Fr_Rd = (255, 0, 0)
Lht_Orng = (255, 128, 0)
#END OF COLOUR MODULE

display_width = 800
display_height = 600



gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hard Drive')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bg = pygame.image.load("asphalt.jpg")


carImg = pygame.image.load('car1.png')
car_width = 45
car_height = 45

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def middle_road(roadx, roady, roadw, roadh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [roadx, roady, roadw, roadh])

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, Blck)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()



def crash():
    message_display('You Crashed')

def game_loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 7
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    middle_road_starty = display_height
    middle_road_speed = 7
    middle_road_width = 50
    middle_road_height = 75
    middle_road_startx = (0, display_width/2)

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change

        gameDisplay.fill(Wht)

        #INSIDE OF THE GAME LOOP
        gameDisplay.blit(bg, (0, 0))

        #thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color
        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, Cyn)
        thing_starty += thing_speed

        car(x,y)
        middle_road(middle_road_startx, middle_road_starty, middle_road_width, middle_road_height, Wht)
        middle_road_starty += middle_road_speed

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < 0:
            crash()

        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)

        if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
            print('y crossover')

            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx + thing_width:
                print('x crossover')
                crash()


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Now here is the error:

```
Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 10 2011, 21:51:15) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aidan\Desktop\PyGame\frame.py", line 144, in <module>
    game_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Aidan\Desktop\PyGame\frame.py", line 123, in game_loop
    middle_road(middle_road_startx, middle_road_starty, middle_road_width, middle_road_height, Wht)
  File "C:\Users\Aidan\Desktop\PyGame\frame.py", line 48, in middle_road
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [roadx, roady, roadw, roadh])
TypeError: Rect argument is invalid
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>>
```

Why is Rect not valid? If it works for the "thing" object, why cant it work for the "middle_road" object? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that middle_road_startx is a tuple and not a int:

```
middle_road_startx = (0, display_width/2)
```

Looking at the rest of the code I guess this is what you want:

```
middle_road_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width/2)
```

**EDIT**

However not part of your question, in the comments you express that you want the object in the middle of screen, replace these lines:

```
middle_road_starty = display_height
middle_road_speed = 7 # if you want it static in the middle why would it have speed?
middle_road_width = 50
middle_road_height = 75
middle_road_startx = (0, display_width/2)
```

With:

```
middle_road_speed = 7 # if you want it static in the middle why would it have speed?
middle_road_width = 50
middle_road_height = 75
middle_road_startx = (display_width/2) - (middle_road_width/2)
middle_road_starty = (display_height/2) - (middle_road_height/2)
```

So first calculate the middle of the screen `(display_width/2)`,`(display_height/2)` and then offset for the width/height of object you wanna draw there `(middle_road_width/2)`,`(middle_road_height/2)`

Comment: Actually, its close, but I want the blocks(the code above) to appear only in the center of the screen. I dont want any collisions with them as they are only aesthetic. However the code above mimics the other block I have the gets drawn to the screen.